# Cannot run Django app. ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, gunicorn

### What I want to achieve

I want to run a Django app by AWS EC2, Nginx and Gunicorn.

### The problem that is occurring

I started Nginx and Gunicorn successfully (that was checked by `systemctl status` and`ps ax | grep gunicorn`, respectively), but when I open `http://<ElasticIP>/` from chrome, I get the following error.

```
This site can’t be reached.
<ElasticIP> refused to connect.

Try:
Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall

ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

My /etc/nginx/nginx.conf is as follows. Also, I have opened 80th port.

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name <Elastic IP>;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;

        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location /static {
          alias /usr/share/nginx/html/static;
        }

        location /media {
          alias /usr/share/nginx/html/media;
        }

        location / {
          proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x _forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

          proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        }

...
...
    }
```

I would be grateful if you could help me out.

Comment: Did you open port 80 in the instance security group?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes, I opened port 80 in the instance security group.

Comment: When you login to the instance, and `curl` your website from localhost, does it work?

Comment: (I think) it's working.

```
*   Trying <Elastic IP>...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to <Elastic IP> (<Elastic IP>) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: <Elastic IP>
> User-Agent: curl/7.61.1
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Server: nginx/1.16.1
< Date: Sat, 06 Jun 2020 04:44:29 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< Location: https://<Elastic IP>/
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< 
* Connection #0 to host <Elastic IP> left intact
```

Comment: You didn’t share your gunicorn configuration... although it does appear to be not connecting before nginx is hit.

Comment: I tired, and `curl http://localhost` returns empty. What can I do?